# Python ThreadPoolExecutor: Not working as expected?

Tags: python, multithreading

According to [realpython](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#working-with-many-threads):

> The end of the with block causes the ThreadPoolExecutor to do a .join() on each of the threads in the pool. It is strongly recommended that you use ThreadPoolExecutor as a context manager when you can so that you never forget to .join() the threads.

```py
import logging
# import threading
import time
import concurrent.futures

def thread_function(name):
    logging.info("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Thread %s: finishing", name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        executor.map(thread_function, range(3))

    print("all done")
```

In the given code snippet, I was expecting that the last line - `print("all done")` to be executed at the end (i.e. after all the threads are done executing). However, it is not? what am I missing?

Comment: On my machine the ```print("all done")``` statement ran last, as expected.

Comment: @daktoad Try it a few times and you will see output like this https://pastebin.com/fyC9EqQk

Comment: That is interesting. I just tried it on another machine several times and it still all consistent. Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: @daktoad I am on Linux, here is the screen shot of the output https://imgur.com/a/lh6ex27

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the way the Pycharm console buffers output (that you showed in your screenshot)

I run it several times in pycharm and it worked sometimes, while not working other times. However, when you run it in the terminal (or tell pycharm to "emulate terminal output") I don't see it anymore

Comment: Yes, that's what happens.